# Como validar se uma String já existe na lista do JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Segue o código que estou travado, gostaria de saber como faço pra validar se um diretório que vou adicionar, já existe no `JComboBox`?

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class JanelaJavaEasyDirectoryMinimizado extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    JanelaJavaEasyDirectoryMinimizado frame = new JanelaJavaEasyDirectoryMinimizado();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JanelaJavaEasyDirectoryMinimizado() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 308);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //Abaixo é para adicionar um novo diretório ao comboBox
        JLabel lblDiretorio = new JLabel("Diretório:");
        lblDiretorio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblDiretorio.setBounds(59, 40, 68, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDiretorio);

        JTextField campoNovoDiretorio = new JTextField();
        campoNovoDiretorio.setBounds(144, 38, 264, 20);
        contentPane.add(campoNovoDiretorio);
        campoNovoDiretorio.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAddDiretorio = new JButton("Adicionar diretório");
        btnAddDiretorio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String novoDiretorio = campoNovoDiretorio.getText();

                JComboBox campoDiretorio = SingletonComboDiretorio.getInstance();
                campoDiretorio.addItem(novoDiretorio);

                DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)campoDiretorio.getModel();

                if (novoDiretorio.isEmpty())
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                else if (model.getIndexOf(campoDiretorio) != -1) //PROBLEMA DE VALIDAÇÃO NESSA PARTE
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diretório ja existe, adicione outro!");
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diretório adicionado à lista:\n " + novoDiretorio, "Mensagem",
                            1);
            }
        });
        btnAddDiretorio.setBounds(143, 68, 264, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnAddDiretorio);

        //Abaixo é área para poder selecionar o diretório que contém no comboBox e o nome da pasta.
        JLabel lblDiretrio = new JLabel("Diret\u00F3rio:");
        lblDiretrio.setToolTipText("Selecione um diret\u00F3rio.");
        lblDiretrio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblDiretrio.setBounds(59, 140, 68, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDiretrio);

        JComboBox campoDiretorio = SingletonComboDiretorio.getInstance();
        campoDiretorio.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Sem diretório" }));
        campoDiretorio.setBounds(144, 140, 264, 20);
        contentPane.add(campoDiretorio);

        JLabel lblNomeDoArquivo = new JLabel("Nome da pasta:");
        lblNomeDoArquivo.setToolTipText("Insira o nome da pasta que deseja criar.");
        lblNomeDoArquivo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblNomeDoArquivo.setBounds(15, 170, 112, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNomeDoArquivo);

        JTextField campoNomeDoArquivo = new JTextField();
        campoNomeDoArquivo.setBounds(144, 170, 264, 20);
        contentPane.add(campoNomeDoArquivo);
        campoNomeDoArquivo.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnCriarDiretrio = new JButton("Criar diret\u00F3rio");
        btnCriarDiretrio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String nomeDirDesejado = (String) campoDiretorio.getSelectedItem();

                String nomePasta = campoNomeDoArquivo.getText();

                File novaPasta = new File(nomeDirDesejado, nomePasta);
                novaPasta.mkdir();

                if (nomePasta.isEmpty())
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diretório criado em:\n" + nomeDirDesejado + "\\" + nomePasta, "Mensagem", 1);

            }
        });
        btnCriarDiretrio.setBounds(150, 200, 126, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnCriarDiretrio);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setBounds(0, 115, 434, 14);
        contentPane.add(separator);

        JLabel lblRenanNarciso = new JLabel("Renan Narciso - 2017");
        lblRenanNarciso.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblRenanNarciso.setBounds(144, 244, 155, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblRenanNarciso);

    }
}

//Classe criada sob o padrão de projeto Singleton para poder usar um JComboBox estatático.
class SingletonComboDiretorio {

    private static JComboBox compoDiretorio;

    private SingletonComboDiretorio() {

    }

    public static synchronized JComboBox getInstance() {
        if (compoDiretorio == null) {
            compoDiretorio = new JComboBox();
        }
        return compoDiretorio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132) a [essa pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132).

Comment: Um tópico eu tenho dúvida ao inserir dados em tempo de execução. Esse tópico eu tenho dúvida ao validar uma string com algum dado do comboBox. Já ja irei editar e por o código...

Comment: Código postado no tópico.

Comment: Você quer checar se a string está contida a lista de itens do combobox ou somente o item que está selecionado no combo?

Comment: checar se a string que vou adicionar atualmente ja tem nos itens contido no combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema que ocorre é que você está passando para o método `indexOf` verificar se já existia na lista o próprio objeto que representa seu combo e não a string recém digitada. Há outro problema também no código, você adiciona o nome do diretório no combo antes de validá-lo, ou seja, se for repetido ou em branco, vai ser adicionado do mesmo jeito, tornando inútil as condições que seguem no *listener* do botão `btnAddDiretorio`.

A forma correta do `actionPerfomed` deveria ser assim:

```
btnAddDiretorio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        String novoDiretorio = campoNovoDiretorio.getText();

        JComboBox campoDiretorio = SingletonComboDiretorio.getInstance();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) campoDiretorio.getModel();

        if (novoDiretorio.isEmpty())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome do diretório não pode ser em branco!");
        else if (model.getIndexOf(novoDiretorio) != -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diretório ja existe, adicione outro!");
        } else {
            campoDiretorio.addItem(novoDiretorio);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diretório adicionado à lista:\n " + novoDiretorio, "Mensagem",
                    1);
        }
    }
});
```

Lembrando que o método [`getIndexOf(Object anItem)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#getIndexOf-java.lang.Object-) retorna o índice do item, caso ele exista no model do `JComboBox`, e `-1` se ele não foi localizado, por isso a validação é checar se ele retorna diferente de -1.

É importante salientar que, caso você tenha criado um `ComboModel` próprio, você deve alterar o cast de `DefaultComboBoxModel` para o seu `ComboModel`.

Comment: Po, fiz isso aqui é continuou entrando diretórios repetidos.

Comment: @RenanNarciso provavelmente há algum detalhe diferente, se tiver um espaço a mais esse método não vai validar como  repetido. Notei que a informação vem de um campo de texto, pode ser isso. Tente copiar exatamente um diretorio que já exista e colar no campo para ver se passa.

Comment: no if, ao invés de eu colocar != -1, eu coloquei == -1 e apareceu a janela informando que o diretório já existe. Bom a mensagem aparece mas o diretório é adicionado. Acho que fazendo essa parte ai do código num try/catch resolveria, nao?

Comment: Quer dizer, com o código == -1 mesmo n tenso colocado nenhum item ao comboBox, aparece a msg dizendo q já possui tal item

Comment: @RenanNarciso -1 é o resultado da comparação, só retorna isso se o item não existir no combo. Se já existir, retorna o indice dele na lista do combo, por isso a comparação precisa retornar diferente de -1, pois significa que já existe. Não há necessidade de try/catch, só isso ai resolve o problema de duplicata, releia meu comentario anterior, a causa não é esta lógica e sim como os textos estão chegando.

Comment: Sim, li seu comentário anterior. Coloquei o mesmo diretório seguido do outro e passa

Comment: @RenanNarciso então será necessário um exemplo reproduzivel e executável do seu código para testar onde está o problema provavelmente.

Comment: Como faço pra enviar um arquivo reproduzível aqui?

Comment: @RenanNarciso você pode adicionar na pergunta, clicando em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/178157/edit)

Comment: Ok, quando eu chegar do trab, mando aqui.

Comment: Código editado e adicionado ao post. O problema está na linha 80.
PS: minimizei o código para tudo dar em apenas um JFrame e na mesma classe.

Comment: @RenanNarciso localizei o problema, veja a edição. Há outros problema no seu código, sugiro que verifique o actionPerformed do botao `btnCriarDiretrio` ele também está com problemas. Só não mostrei na resposta porque sairia do que foi perguntado.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!

Só não entendi mto bem essa linha como vc disse acima...
`model.getIndexOf(novoDiretorio) != -1`

e o porque teve que usar a classe `DefaultComboBoxModel` para criar um ComboBox

Comment: @RenanNarciso o que essa linha faz é recuperar o model do combo, não criá-lo novamente. Todo componente em swing tem um modelo que define como os itens serão exibidos dentro dele, o defaultcomboboxmodel é que armazena todos os itens do combo, bem como operações com eles(adicao, remocao, edicao), por isso recuperei uma instancia dele, pois para verificar se um item existe, somente consultando o modelo.[...]

Comment: @RenanNarciso[...] quando você faz  `combo.addItem()` na verdade o java chama o modelo deste combo e faz a adição nele, pois o combo em si não armazena seus itens.

Comment: Se o getIndexOf retorna -1 é true, logo se já existe o diretório no combo, retorna -1. Então é executado o JOpitionPane, correto?

Comment: @RenanNarciso veja a linha que eu explico novamente: *O método getIndexOf(Object anItem) retorna o indice de um elemento, caso ele exista no model do  JComboBox, e -1 se ele não foi localizado.* Ou seja, se ele achar um objeto no model, e esse objeto for o quarto da lista, ele retornará 3(listas começam por 0 em java), se não achar, retorna -1.

Comment: @RenanNarciso a resposta lhe atendeu? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` ao lado esquerdo, assim, ela fica como referencia para outras pessoas com problemas semelhantes :)